# What is the state of the art in Memory Protection?

Tags: memory-management

The more I read about low level languages like C and pointers and memory management, it makes me wonder about the current state of the art with modern operating systems and memory protection. For example what kind of checks are in place that prevent some rogue program from randomly trying to read as much address space as it can and disregard the rules set in place by the operating system?

In general terms how do these memory protection schemes work? What are their strength and weaknesses? To put it another way, are there things that simply cannot be done anymore when running a compiled program in a modern OS even if you have C and you own compiler with whatever tweaks you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protection is enforced by the hardware (i.e., by the CPU). Applications can only express addresses as virtual addresses and the CPU resolves the mapping of virtual address to physical address using [lookaside buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_Lookaside_Buffer). Whenever the CPU needs to resolve an unknown address it generates a 'page fault' which interrupts the current running application and switches control to the operating system. The operating system is responsible for looking up its internal structures ([page tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table)) and find a mapping between the virtual address touched by the application and the actual physical address. Once the mapping is found the CPU can resume the application.

The CPU instructions needed to load a mapping between a physical address and a virtual one are protected and as such can only be executed by a protected component (ie. the OS kernel).

Overall the scheme works because:

- applications cannot address physical memory
- resolving mapping from virtual to physical requires protected operations
- only the OS kernel is allowed to execute protected operations

The scheme fails though if a rogue module is loaded in the kernel, because at that protection level it can read and write into any physical address.

Application *can* read and write other processes memory, but only by asking the kernel to do this operation for them (eg. in Win32 [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx)), and such APIs are protected by access control (certain privileges are required on the caller).

Answer (score 4):

Memory protection is enforced in hardware, typically with a minimum granularity on the order of KBs.

From the Wikipedia article about [memory protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection):

> In paging, the memory address space is
>   divided into equal, small pieces,
>   called pages. Using a virtual memory
>   mechanism, each page can be made to
>   reside in any location of the physical
>   memory, or be flagged as being
>   protected. Virtual memory makes it
>   possible to have a linear virtual
>   memory address space and to use it to
>   access blocks fragmented over physical
>   memory address space.
>
> Most computer architectures based on
>   pages, most notably x86 architecture,
>   also use pages for memory protection.
>
> A page table is used for mapping
>   virtual memory to physical memory. The
>   page table is usually invisible to the
>   process. Page tables make it easier to
>   allocate new memory, as each new page
>   can be allocated from anywhere in
>   physical memory.
>
> By such design, it is impossible for
>   an application to access a page that
>   has not been explicitly allocated to
>   it, simply because any memory address,
>   even a completely random one, that
>   application may decide to use, either
>   points to an allocated page, or
>   generates a page fault (PF) error.
>   Unallocated pages simply do not have
>   any addresses from the application
>   point of view.

Comment: "most notably x86" is amusing.  Sure all the major x86 OSes use paging now because paging works well, but in 32 and 16 bit mode you could use just segmentation without paging for memory protection.  (64-bit mode neuters segmentation, leaving paging as the only viable option.)  And 8086 / 186 / 286 don't have paging.  Most non-x86 ISAs *only* have paging as a memory protection mechanism.  If I was writing that, I'd say "most architectures ... (including the very common x86) ...".  Fortunately someone's already changed Wikip's wording.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask Google for Segmentation fault, Memory Violation Error and General Protection Failure. These are errors returned by various OSes in response for a program trying to access memory address it shouldn't access.

And Windows Vista (or 7) has routines for randomized dll attaching, which means that buffer overflow can take you to different addresses each time it occurs. This also makes buffer overflow attack a little bit less repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

So, to link together the answers posted with your question. A program that attempts to read any memory address that is not mapped in its address space, will cause the processor to issue a page fault exception transferring execution control to the operating system code (trusted code), the kernel will then check which is the faulty address, if there is no mapping in the current process address space, it will send the SIGSEV (segmentation fault) signal to the process which typically kills the process (talking about Linux/Unix here), on Windows you get something along the same lines.

Note: you can take a look at mprotect() in Linux and POSIX operating systems, it allows you to protect pages of memory explicitly, functions like malloc() return memory on pages with default protection, which you can then modify, this way you can protect areas of memory as read only (but just in page size chunks, typically around 4KB).